# Отмена минусования вопроса

Tags: обсуждение

Можно ли отменить свой минус с вопроса, при этом чтобы он не превратился в плюс. К примеру к вопросу с нулевым рейтингом был поставлен "-", но после редактирования вопроса было принято решение отменить этот "-". Почему рейтинг у вопроса становится "+1"?

Comment: Да. Повторным нажатием на -.

Comment: @PashaPash, спасибо! Все намного проще, чем я предполагал! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно. Надо просто ещё раз нажать ту же кнопку.

Comment: Я замечал, что если это сделать не сразу, а подумав, скажем, пару минут, то уже не получается. Система говорит что-то вроде -- вы уже отметили, подождите пока вопрос (или ответ) не будет изменен.

Comment: @avp, 5 минут даётся, либо после правки сообщения.